# how to override this hashCode method?

Tags: java

as for the definition of Person:

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private int characteristics;
    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
           if (obj == this) {
                 return true;
           }
           if (obj instanceof Person) {
                 if (id == ((Person) obj).id) {
                     return true;
                 } else if (characteristics == ((Person) obj).characteristics) {
                     return true;
                 }
           }
           return false;
    }
}
```

cause 2 `Person` objects `a` and `b` must have the identical hash code if `a.equals(b)` returns `true`, how should I implement the `hashCode` method?

**solution**

my `equals` method implementation is incorrect according to Java's equivalence protocol: *transitivity* is not satisfied: `a.id = 1`, `a.characteristic = 2`, `b.id = 1`, `b.characteristic = 3`, `c.id = 2`, `c.characteristic = 3`; `a.equals(b) == true`, `b.equals(c) == true`, but `a.equals(c) == false`.

Comment: You can XOR the id and characteristics variables.

Comment: For the record, you can convert the second set of those `if`s into returns, ie. `return obj instanceof Person && ( id == ((Person) obj).id || characteristics == ((Person) obj).characteristics);`. You should also take care to `return false` at the end of your current code, since your `equals` method may run without returning anything.

Comment: @SimplyPanda That's completely wrong on the first one.  `return obj == this;` will return false if `obj` is not the same instance, but may still be equal by value.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's illogical to do so in the first case. My bad. I've fixed it.

Comment: @VanDarg two `Person` have the same `id` `0110` but different `characteristic` `0111` and `0101`: if XOR the two fields, they return different hash code `0001` and `0011`, but they should have returned the same hash code.

Comment: `int hashCode(){return 1;}` you can't use the object as key

Comment: From what i heard hashcodes should be created by using values that wont change. If you wont let id and characteristics to be changed you can return their combination like `id*31+characteristics`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your class considers objects equal when either of their respective `id` or `characteristics` fields are equal, the only hash code you can reasonably use here is a constant value for all instances:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
```

This will make hash-based lookups perform horribly.

An either-or test in `equals()` is generally a bad idea; the objects aren't actually *equal*, are they?  Maybe they are just a "match for each other?"  Perhaps you should consider leaving `equals()` alone and implementing some other comparison method.

---

As Thomasz pointed out, your `equals()` test is not transitive; if `a.equals(b) && b.equals(c)` is true then `a.equals(c)` must be true.  This is *not* true with your overload, and therefore **your implementation breaks the contract of `equals()`**.  I would strongly urge you to implement this test in a different method and leave `equals()` alone.

Comment: this is the right answer :) (equals is good for set/collections, just hashcode doesn't work in the OP's case)

Answer (score 1):

This is what [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) auto-generated for your class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id;
    result = 31 * result + characteristics;
    return result;
}
```

And after few refactorings:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * id + characteristics;
}
```

And for the record, is it just me or is your `equals()` broken? You consider two objects equal if either `id`s or `characteristics` are equal, but not necessarily both of them. This means your equality is not *transitive* which might have really unexpected side effects once your object goes into wilderness.

Here is a decent implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Person)) {
        return false;
    }

    Person person = (Person) o;
    return characteristics == person.characteristics && id == person.id;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem exactly right to me, doesn't the OP's equals() method indicate if (id == person.id) || (characteristics == person.characteristics)

Comment: YES: `if (id == person.id) || (characteristics == person.characteristics)`

Comment: @NominSim: you are right. However the definition of `equals()` by OP is not transitive, my `hashCode()` is valid for correct `equals()` - which I noticed later. I accept your downvote with humility, however I believe OP has bigger issue then...

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz thanks for help. this issue can be addressed as follows in general: if two persons have the same id, they are regarded as the same person; or if two persons with different ids have the same characteristics, they are also regarded as the same person. this is reasonable cases in FOL computing.

Comment: @Kejia: I don't know what *FOL computing* is, I am sure you know your domain. What I am saying is that when having three people, `A`, `B` and `C`, `A` and `B` are equal because they have the same `id` but different `characteristics`. `B` and `C` are equal because they have same `characteristics` but different `id`. However, `A` and `C` are **not** equal, which might have serious consequences once you start using such object e.g. in collections.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I mean some first order logic reasoning stuffs. anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz yes, you are totally correct: my `equals` is not *transitive*.

Answer (score 0):

If having the same `id` implies always having the same `characteristics` (which seems necessary for your `equals()` to be valid), then your hash code can use `characteristics` alone:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return characteristics;
}
```

If that's not the case, you may want to reconsider using Java equality to express this relation, as @cdhowie suggests.